# Angular 2 - send data from Child to Parent component

Tags: angular, output

I have a use case where a parent component has two child components. When a child component is selected, the parents FormControl should be reset.

In order to do this, I need to send a boolean value from the children to the parent, but this is not functioning as expected.

Here is my current implementation - which is not working! Could someone explain what I am overlooking? Many thanks

**Child component**

Register the event emitter in the child

```
 @Output() formControlReset: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();
```

emit the event

```
this.formControlReset.emit(true);
```

**Parent Component**

```
<div>
     <input (formControlReset)="formControlReset($event)" [(ngModel)]="userInput" [formControl]="inputFormControl" *ngIf="showSearchInput" placeholder="Search here" #searchInput></input>
</div>
```

call a reset on the formControl

```
formControlReset(value: boolean): void {
    console.log('doing something');
    this.inputFormControl.reset();
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the emitter? it won't work if you try testing it inside constructor. Try adding a button instead. `<button (click)="onClick()">Click </button>`. Then call it `onClick(){this.formControlReset.emit(true);}`

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong with what you posted.

@Input and @Output will only work when you have a parent-child component relationship, it will not work for unrelated component.

My guess is that the child component is not part of the parent component structure.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are not defining your child component using your child component's selector.

Change this:

```
<input (formControlReset)="formControlReset($event)" [(ngModel)]="userInput" [formControl]="inputFormControl" *ngIf="showSearchInput" placeholder="Search here" #searchInput></input>
```

To this:

```
<app-childSelector (formControlReset)="formControlReset($event)" [(ngModel)]="userInput" [formControl]="inputFormControl" *ngIf="showSearchInput" placeholder="Search here" #searchInput></app-childSelector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Folks have covered emitter, which should work fine if you have an actual parent-child component relationship. If these are sibling components instead, you'll need to pass data via a service.